# Java 8 stream compare two objects and run a function on them

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I've a a stream which I want to partition into smaller parts based on matching Id and then apply some proccessing logic on each of the part/element.

```
class BigRequest{
String bId;
List<Parts> parts;
//getters and setter here
}

Class Parts{
String pId;
String partId;
//getters and setter here
}
```

I want to segregate and create a list of Parts of size 10 when the partId of different parts are same.

How to use the filter or reduce or groupingBy function to compare the two elements and put them to a list?
I've tried filter like below, doesn't take p1 variable:

```
big.stream().filter( p -> p.getPartId() == p1.getPartId()) //error
```

Tried groupingBy like this

```
big.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Parts::getPartId) //error
```

I want to iterate  over the filtered/reduced list a another and call another function called abc(). How can I do it using Java Streams?

pseudo:

```
big.getParts().stream.
//dividing logic logic
for(i < parts.size)
    abc(p)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your error comes because you have a list of `BigRequest`, yet you are calling `Parts::getPartId` on it, which is the same as calling `BigRequest.getPartId()` (not going to work). You will have to `flatMap(bigParts -> bigParts.parts.stream())` and *then* it'll allow you to use `Parts::getPartId`.

Comment: However, it's usually not possible to create backpressure in stream by collecting `Stream<T>` into some kind of `Stream<List<T>>` - streams are by design operations on only single element at a time. You can unwrap `Stream<List<T>>` into a `Stream<T>`, but the opposite is not available for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like this:

```
 Map<String,List<Parts>> commonId = big.getParts().
                stream().
                collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Parts::getPartId,
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                Function.identity(),
                                Collectors.toList()
                            )
                        )
                );
```

and after it, you will just need to iterate over the map and apply your function. 
 `commonId.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> apply(entry))...`

**Updated**
We can omit `Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),Collectors.toList())` part, since it is a default behaviour of [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Map<String,List<Parts>> commonId = big.getParts().
                    stream().
                    collect(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Parts::getPartId
                            )
                    );
```

Comment: Normal `groupingBy` collector is already `mapping(identity(), toList())`, is it not?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, yes, you are totally right. We don't need - `Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),Collectors.toList())`  part

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: well, `groupingBy` uses `toList()` by default and `mapping(identity(), …)` is even more redundant.

Comment: @Holger, to be honest, I was always using `Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),Collectors.toList())`, I never new that `toList()` is default behaviour of `groupingBy`. What a shame! I will read java docs more carefully now.

Comment: But what is the purpose of wrapping a collector into a `mapping(identity(), …)` collector?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, but can you please show how to apply the function abc(List<Parts> obj) over the map. Also how can I return a Set<Parts> in Map<String,Set<Parts>? Collectors.toSet() throws error

Comment: @Holger, I know that it doesn't make any sense, I didn't pay close attention to what mapping method does. I was doing it before, but now I know that there is a better way

Comment: @user2340345, What is the signature of your method? it might be something like `commonId.values().stream().map(YourObject::abc)` or `commonId.values().stream().forEach(YourObject::abc)`.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc The signature is List<Set<Parts>> myfunc(BigObject big). How can I do the same with the reduce() function instead of groupingBy()?