# Split a Collection(using java 8 streams) into smaller components based on different parameters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is a continuation of this question [Java 8 stream compare two objects and run a function on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118328/java-8-stream-compare-two-objects-and-run-a-function-on-them)

```
Class BigRequest{
    String bId;
    List<Parts> parts;
    //getters and setter here
    }

Class Parts{
String pId;
String partId;
//getters and setter here
}
```

My question is to split a Collection(using java 8 streams) into smaller components based on some dynamic parameters. 
The Dynamic params can change based on different conditions (here, Ive given example as getPartId() being the same) passed to the method splitParts, whose return type is List of Set of Parts

```
List<Set<Parts>> splitParts(BigRequest big){}
```

I've tried the following:

```
 //groupingBy function but that returns a Map 
   Map<String, List<Parts>> parts = big.getParts().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Parts::getPartId));

//doesn't do it accurately
    big.getParts().stream().filter(p -> p.getPartId.equals(p.getPartId())).collect();
```

How do I split a stream based on the dynamic params(maybe by calling a functional interface over reduce method) and then run a method over it?

My function's signature is

```
List<Set<Parts>> splitParts(BigObject b){}
```

I assume doing something like this might help to keep the splitting condition dynamic, but Im not sure how to do it?

```
 big.getParts().stream().reduce(MyFuncInterface::divide);
```

and then using forEach(), I think i can iterate over the List and call the abc() method.

How can I do it better?

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is very unclear. What do BigObject and Parts look like, and what should your splitParts method do. Be as precise as the javadoc on such a method should be.

Comment: What should your splitParts method do? Be as precise as the javadoc on such a method should be.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet that your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "dynamic params", "change based on input type", "calling a functional interface over reduce method"? None of these phrases make a lot of sense. You will need to reword your question to be less ambiguous if you want some effective help.

Comment: what would be the order of the `List` of `Set`s? If it's orderless, then you want the result to be a `Collection` of `Set`s

Comment: @f.khantsis I want List of Set coz I want to index the elements later on.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a `List<Set<Parts>>`, first change your code to get a `Map<String, Set<Parts>>`:

```
Map<String, Set<Parts>> parts = big.getParts().stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Parts::getPartId, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Calling `parts.values()` will return a `Collection<Set<Parts>>`, so convert the `Collection` to a `List`:

```
List<Set<Parts>> list = new ArrayList<>(parts.values());
```

Or you could just re-stream it, so you can do it in a single call chain:

```
List<Set<Parts>> list = big.getParts()
                           .stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Parts::getPartId,
                                                          Collectors.toSet()))
                           .values()
                           .stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I assume the complexity will be very high in this case as we're converting to Set and then to List. Another thing, how can I make the condition `Parts::getPartId` as dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic in what way? `Collectors.groupingBy()` requires a `Function<Parts,String>` as the first parameter. You can declare a variable of that type and assign any compatible method reference, lambda expression, or anonymous implementation to it.

Comment: Why do you *"assume the complexity will be very high"*? The entire operation is _O(n)_.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Dynamic in the way of partitioning.

Comment: @user2340345: can you stop using the word “dynamic” and just describe what you want to do?

Comment: By dynamic I mean the way the BigRequest is partitioned can be changed by changing the partitioning logic - by PartId or by other parameters in the Parts POJO or by the free thread pool capacity.

Comment: @user2340345 You can partition any way you want, as long as you can come up with a `String` value that defines the partition. All `Parts` that map to the same `String` value will be in the same partition, as mapped by the `Function<Parts,String>` you supply to `groupingBy`.

Comment: Actually, using the single chain variant, there isn’t even a dependency to the group criterion type, so any `Function<Parts,?>` will do; there’s no requirement to produce a `String` anymore. In the two step variant, you have to change the map declaration to `Map<?, Set<Parts>> parts` to be independent of the group criterion type. Then, it can also accept any `Function<Parts,?>`.